# Why can I not update to the newest version of libtorch?

Tags: cmake, pytorch

I followed the tutorial here to make a c++ front-end application for pytorch:

```
https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/cpp_frontend.html
```

I used GPU version. I could succesfully cmake and make.

Now I updated to the latest version of libtorch. I can still cmake, but on make, I get the following error:

```
[willem@int2 build]$ make
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/sw/arch/RedHatEnterpriseServer7/EB_production/2019/software/cuDNN/7.6.5.32-CUDA-10.1.243/include/lib64', needed by `polIter'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/polIter.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

My cmake command is:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=~/libtorch1.8.1/share/cmake/Torch/    
 -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH=/home/willemvj/libtorch1.8.1/share/cmake/Torch/ 
-DCUDNN_LIBRARY_PATH=$EBROOTCUDNN/include/lib64 
-DCUDNN_INCLUDE_DIR=$EBROOTCUDNN/include -DCUDNN_LIBRARY=$EBROOTCUDNN/lib64
/libcudnn.so.7 .. #
```

Any ideas on what is causing this?

Comment: This is not a programming question. In addition, it's lacking lots of information.

Comment: @gspr Ok sorry. Any place where I could ask this?

Comment: @willem: You may ask there, but you actually need to provide more details. E.g. the error message contains the path `/sw/arch/RedHatEnterpriseServer7/EB_production/2019/software/cuDNN/7.6.5.32-CUDA-10.1.243/include/lib64` which is unnatural for a CMake project. You provided that path **manually** in some variable, don't you?

Comment: @willem: SuperUser maybe.

Comment: cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=~/libtorch1.8.1/share/cmake/Torch/ -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH=/home/willemvj/libtorch1.8.1/share/cmake/Torch/ -DCUDNN_LIBRARY_PATH=$EBROOTCUDNN/include/lib64 -DCUDNN_INCLUDE_DIR=$EBROOTCUDNN/include -DCUDNN_LIBRARY=$EBROOTCUDNN/lib64/libcudnn.so.7 ..
#

Comment: @Tsyvarev see the comment for the command I used. I am on a supercomputer and I wish to point to the location of cuDNN.

Comment: Variable `CUDNN_LIBRARY_PATH` is expected to point to the **library** (**file**), but you set it to the **directory**.

Comment: On Stack Overflow we expect all information about the problem to be in the **question post** itself, not in the *comments*. With 2k+ reputation you should be aware of that...